# Android studio slide the button up

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

With these codes, I can slide the button left and right as much as I want.

```
<Button
    android:text="Paylaş"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/y"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="paylas"/>
```

well how can i slide it up or down as much as i want?

Comment: please share your activity.xml code

Comment: I updated plsss

Comment: can you please upload some image sample so that I can understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: in your code you are using, android:layout_alignParentEnd="true", and then you are also using  android:layout_marginEnd="140dp", why?.

Comment: It will be better if you share the full xml code